# Multiple component with multiple models

Tags: ember.js

So, I'm building an EmberJS application and I have a route, containing multiple components (e.g. `messages` and `questions`).

Each component is extended with a `dyn-widget` mixin that allows it to be dragged by the user across the screen, as they are presented to the user as windows on a canvas.

To store the information about each `dyn-widget` window, I use three Ember Data models: a `dyn-widget` that stores values shared by any widget (position, size...), and a `dyn-widget/questions` and a `dyn-widget/chat` that contain additional information about how the widget is set up and a one-to-one relationship to the 'parent' `dyn-widget` model.

The route has a corresponding controller that allows the user to instianciate new windows. The controller then creates a `dyn-widget/whatever` model along with the associated `dyn-widget` model, and everything is stored in the local storage.

However, when I try to implement the `model()` function into the route, I've found that I can't really return multiple, different models without hacky solutions. I thought of putting the models directly into my components but that breaks the following pattern:

```
Components are isolated entities that consume data through their
interface, react to data changes that flow via data binding, and 
possibly send up named actions.
```

So how should I approach this? What would the a non-hacky, Ember way to this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that model in ember by convection  cannot return multiple models for a route. If you look at the documentation

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_multiple-models

you can use Ember.RSVP.hash to resolve multiple resources

sample router code:

```
model(params) {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    messages: this.store.findAll('message'),
    questions: this.store.findAll('question')
  });
},
```

In this way you can feed your components with data from multiple models directly from router - so the pattern is that components gets the data and send the actions to route or controller.

This is a standard way of doing things and it was in ember from 1.x release

I hope this will help you.

Comment: ...damn you're right. I actually found that I could use `Ember.RSVP.hash` earlier, but I discarded it as I forgot that the store returned promises (being tired and using adapters for non-async storages do that, I guess), so I discarded it as a hack. Sorry and thanks a lot for your time!